# Import data from Oracle to Microsoft SQL database

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, replication

My customer have two database servers, one for Oracle and one for Microsoft SQL. Two servers are located in the same network. 
Their requirement is when table A (for example) of Oracle database is changed, the data must be synchronized to table B of Microsoft SQL database.
So I intend to raise a trigger in table A when it has insert or update statement. However, how can I insert the changed data from Oracle to Microsoft SQL directly ?

Because my SQL Sever edition is Standard, I can't use SQL Server Replication for. Any other idea ?
Thanks all !

Comment: Linked servers and `OPENQUERY` or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152481.aspx

Comment: Unclear why the downvotes, the problem/question is valid with no ambiguity.  SQL Server Replication with oracle publisher is a common solution.

Comment: Thanks lad2025 and @Greg ! I'm also disappointed about why they were downvotes my question without any explain !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Replication defining an Oralce publisher:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152481.aspx